# How would I reduce the texture visible on old photos in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Many old photos have an annoying bubble-like texture. I have tested some methods of noise reduction in the filter menu but the result was not good. What effective methods could be used for reducing this texture?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use a fourier transform plugin - [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyox358zIRw)

Comment: as an aside: The texture is usually due to the way the scanner illuminates objects (the scanner wand and light source are right next to each other and you get glare). One way to avoid it is by using a DSLR camera with a camera stand, a polarizing filter on the lens, and polarized lights.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a photoshop plugin called Dfine 2 it is a part of Nik collection by google.Noise can be reduced by using this plugin.

**Tip:You cannot remove the noise totally but yes you can reduce it.**